# Export Correlation Heatmap to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, correlation

I am trying to export my correlation heatmap to excel. I can't find any documentation/syntax on this by python

```
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_precision(2)

corr.style. \
    apply(background_gradient, axis=None).\
    to_excel("mev_corr_matrix.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")



I want to export the heatmap as is to excel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain both code together with `.`:

```
(corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
           .to_excel("mev_corr_matrix.xlsx", engine="openpyxl"))
```

If need change [`precision`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Precision):

```
(corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
           .set_precision(2)
           .to_excel("mev_corr_matrix.xlsx", engine="openpyxl"))
```